# Need to Stop Scrolling Dot Matrix printer After finish Printing

Tags: java, printing, dot-matrix

I am trying to print invoice. The printer should scroll the page after it print the last line of the invoice. So the page need not to readjust manually for next invoice printing. My objective is  stop scrolling the printer after it print last line.I am using `java language` to develop the application. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you have tried so far? don't ask for a ready made solution.

Comment: @WasiAhmad sorry to say but i have no idea how to do this. can i do this whit java coding or i need some printer setting?